# Windows Server 2003 Print the Server Configuration

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, configuration, printing

Should be an easy question for you guys.

In Windows Server 2008 it is possible to print or mail the whole server configuration.
Is there also a function like this in Windows Server 2003?

Answer (score 0):

Start, Run: dxdiag

Once it completes you can click the "Save All Information..." button at the bottom and it will dump everything to a textfile.

Comment: I thought dxdiag was DirectX Diagnostics....  Di it change? Pity I don't have a Windows 2k8 box to try on. :-(

Comment: It is. However, it also outputs a lot with regards to hardware configuration.

Comment: Yes, of course. hardware Configuration. But the function in Server 2008 prints the Software and Service configuration. That's what I'm searching for.